# Return a list in an observable

Tags: angular

Please check the code below, why is it not working?
I have an observable with a list of journeys, i want to filter these and return it as an Array of Journeys.

```
  private onTest (id: number): Journey[] {

    this.allJourneys$.map(journeyList => {
      return journeyList.filter(journey => journey.comPoints.some(jcompoint => jcompoint.id === id));
    });
  }
```

Comment: this method does not return something, but i dont get it why

Comment: Because there is no `return` ??

Comment: Which version of `RxJS` does the project use? If `v6+`, this will throw error.

Comment: there is a return

Comment: Your `return` returns to the `map` callback, not the `onTest` function. Your function returns nothing.

Comment: can you specify the full use case .. so we can give you a complete solution, where will you use the `onTest` method ?

Answer (score 0):

You have no `return` statement

```
 this.allJourneys$.map(journeyList => {
```

should be probably

```
return this.allJourneys$.map(journeyList => {
```

Obviously at the end, you have to `subscribe` for result as this is async code.

```
onTest(123).subscribe(list=>{list will be here. Do whatever you like with it});
```

Comment: return journeyList.filter(journey => journey.comPoints.some(jcompoint => jcompoint.id === id));

Comment: @Pseudalitos thast return in mapping clousure. Now you must return what was mapped.

Comment: But i dont want to return an Observable, i want to return an Array out of the observable, how can i do this then?

Comment: You can't. You can return an Observable and subscribe to it.

Comment: It is possible don't do that. It will freeze whole application in case of IO latency. Use async code in async way - the proper way.

Comment: and how should look the async call? like this: (onTest(123) | async)

Comment: Its in my answer.

Comment: then i get this error: binding expression can not contain assignments

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async`/`await` and `Promise`, to await the call of service till its finish:

first , you should import `toPromise` like this :

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'
```

then the method should be like that :

```
private async onTest (id: number): Journey[] {
   const result = await this.allJourneys$.toPromise(); // converts the Observable to a Promise
   return result.filter(journey => journey.comPoints.some(jcompoint => jcompoint.id === id));  
}
```

Note that every method that calls `onTest` method should be called with `await` keyword.